# Search between dates in an Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm working on my capstone project where I'm making a database for a facility to log fall, abuse, and behavioral incidents. I want to give the user the ability to search by certain criteria in a date range, but I'm having some problems with the query.

This example is for the search by MRN function, where the user can enter a patient's MRN to see all events (fall, behavior, abuse) in their record. I want there to be a date search integrated into the MRN search. Here is the query that I have so far:

```
SELECT DemographicsTable.MRN, DemographicsTable.[First Name], DemographicsTable.[Last Name], [Abuse Table].[Date of Event], [Abuse Table].[Staff Name(s)], [Abuse Table].Unit, [Abuse Table].Shift, [Abuse Table].Location, [Abuse Table].[Other Location], [Abuse Table].Incident, [Abuse Table].[Abuse Type], [Abuse Table].[Other Abuse Type], [Abuse Table].[Unsubstantial/ Substantial], [Abuse Table].Description, [Abuse Table].Medications, [Abuse Table].Diagnoses, [Abuse Table].Behaviors, [Abuse Table].Intervention
FROM DemographicsTable 
INNER JOIN [Abuse Table] 
ON DemographicsTable.MRN = [Abuse Table].MRN
WHERE ((([Abuse Table].[Date of Event]) Between Forms!DMVAForm!frmSearches!searchByMRNForm!txtStartDate And Forms!DMVAForm!frmSearches!searchByMRNForm!txtEndDate Or Forms!DMVAForm!frmSearches!searchByMRNForm!txtStartDate Is Null)) And ((DemographicsTable.MRN)=forms!DMVAForm!frmSearches!searchByMRNForm!cbMRN) Or (((DemographicsTable.MRN)=forms!DMVAForm!frmSearches!searchByMRNForm!cbMRN))
ORDER BY DemographicsTable.MRN;
```

The form still compiles, however it selects all records for the patient's MRN, not just the records between the dates. I've used the BETWEEN function before on a simpler search and it worked, so I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check your brackets. What does this look like in Design View?

Comment: The end of you SQL WHERE doesn't make any sense. You haven't grouped the MRN clause properly or you have to exclude one of them. Combining AND and OR for same comparison doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Between works for two dates
`Between (dateA and dateB)`. If you have additional ranged ,I sugguest using

```
Where( Between(dateA and dateB) or Between(dateC and dateD) or....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT 
    DemographicsTable.MRN, 
    DemographicsTable.[First Name], 
    DemographicsTable.[Last Name], 
    [Abuse Table].[Date of Event], 
    [Abuse Table].[Staff Name(s)], 
    [Abuse Table].Unit, 
    [Abuse Table].Shift, 
    [Abuse Table].Location, 
    [Abuse Table].[Other Location], 
    [Abuse Table].Incident, 
    [Abuse Table].[Abuse Type], 
    [Abuse Table].[Other Abuse Type],
    [Abuse Table].[Unsubstantial/ Substantial], 
    [Abuse Table].Description, 
    [Abuse Table].Medications, 
    [Abuse Table].Diagnoses, 
    [Abuse Table].Behaviors, 
    [Abuse Table].Intervention
FROM 
    DemographicsTable 
INNER JOIN 
    [Abuse Table] 
    ON DemographicsTable.MRN = [Abuse Table].MRN
WHERE 
    (([Abuse Table].[Date of Event] Between Forms!DMVAForm!frmSearches!searchByMRNForm!txtStartDate And Forms!DMVAForm!frmSearches!searchByMRNForm!txtEndDate) Or (Forms!DMVAForm!frmSearches!searchByMRNForm!txtStartDate Is Null)) 
    And 
    ((DemographicsTable.MRN=forms!DMVAForm!frmSearches!searchByMRNForm!cbMRN) Or (DemographicsTable.MRN=forms!DMVAForm!frmSearches!searchByMRNForm!cbMRN))
ORDER BY 
    DemographicsTable.MRN;
```